# Question about maven

Tags: maven-2

Why is maven downloading dependencies from repository even if the jar exists on my local repository(one reason could be that jar doesn't have a pom), is there a way to get bypass that except with the -o option?

Comment: are they SNAPSHOT dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why is maven downloading [SNAPSHOT] dependencies from repository even if the jar exists on my local repository

Because that's the expected behavior with SNASPSHOT dependencies. Unlike fixed versions, Maven will periodically try to download the most recent version of a given SNAPSHOT. That's extremely useful when you're depending on a project that is under active development. From the *Maven Reference*:

> #### [3.3.1.2. SNAPSHOT Versions](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html#pom-relationships-sect-snapshot-versions)
>
> Maven versions can contain a string
>   literal to signify that a project is
>   currently under active development. If
>   a version contains the string
>   “SNAPSHOT,” then Maven will expand
>   this token to a date and time value
>   converted to UTC (Coordinated
>   Universal Time) when you install or
>   release this component. For example,
>   if your project has a version of
>   “1.0-SNAPSHOT” and you deploy this
>   project’s artifacts to a Maven
>   repository, Maven would expand this
>   version to “1.0-20080207-230803-1” if
>   you were to deploy a release at 11:08
>   PM on February 7th, 2008 UTC. In other
>   words, when you deploy a snapshot, you
>   are not making a release of a software
>   component; you are releasing a
>   snapshot of a component at a specific
>   time.
>
> Why would you use this? SNAPSHOT
>   versions are used for projects under
>   active development. If your project
>   depends on a software component that
>   is under active development, you can
>   depend on a SNAPSHOT release, and
>   Maven will periodically attempt to
>   download the latest snapshot from a
>   repository when you run a build.
>   Similarly, if the next release of your
>   system is going to have a version
>   "1.4", your project would have a
>   version "1.4-SNAPSHOT" until it was
>   formally released.
>
> As a default setting, Maven will not
>   check for SNAPSHOT releases on remote
>   repositories. To depend on SNAPSHOT
>   releases, users must explicitly enable
>   the ability to download snapshots
>   using a `repository` or `pluginRepository`
>   element in the POM.
>
> When releasing a project, you should
>   resolve all dependencies on SNAPSHOT
>   versions to dependencies on released
>   versions. If a project depends on a
>   SNAPSHOT, it is not stable as the
>   dependencies may change over time.
>   Artifacts published to non-snapshot
>   Maven repositories such as
>   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2  cannot
>   depend on SNAPSHOT versions, as
>   Maven's Super POM has snapshot's
>   disabled from the Central repository.
>   SNAPSHOT versions are for development
>   only.

If you **really** want to change this behavior, you can change the `updatePolicy` of your snapshot enabled repository:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>my-repo</id>
    <name>My Corporate Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo.mycompany.com/maven2</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
    ...
    <snapshots>
      <enabled>true</enabled>
      <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
    </snapshots>
  </repository>
```

Switching to `never` will force you to use a manual update (using `mvn -U`). But beware, this is usually not what people want and expect with SNAPSHOTs.

For the record, Maven 3 has a `-nsu, --no-snapshot-updates` command line option allowing to *Suppress SNAPSHOT updates*.

#### See also

- [3.2. The POM](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom.html)
- [Repositories](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) in the POM reference

Comment: tnx , When did maven 3 came out

Comment: @c0mrade: Maven 3 is there for some months now but is not final yet (works fine for me though). Feel free to upvote too by the way, always appreciated :)

Comment: For those using Maven 3, `-nsu` might not work as expected: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5064

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a pom in your local repository by installing the file manually:

```
mvn install:install-file 
    -Dfile=[FILE]
    -DgroupId=[GROUP]
    -DartifactId=[ARTIFACT]
    -Dversion=[VERSION]
    -Dpackaging=jar 
    -DgeneratePom=true
    -DcreateChecksum=true
```

EDIT: You wouldn't want to do this for snapshots.